# 16.04 Desktop folder icon resize

Tags: nautilus, icons

Since upgrading to 16.04 my folders on the desktop and icons in the file manager (nautilus) have grown to ridiculous proportions. I have managed to resize the pdf files on the desktop and can use the list view for the file manager files but not the manager icons. I haven't installed anything since the upgrade(?!) Right clicking and pressing resize icon on individual desktop folders brings up a resize box around the folder but it won't move. All suggestions welcome

[image: desktop screen shot]

[image: file manager screen shot]

Comment: Probably a issue with the theme. Are they smaller when you use the default "human" theme?

Comment: That's certainly made a difference. Thank you. Default theme is ambience but i can resize all by changing the theme